# Iterating through different data sets with LSTM without retaining memories of previous training

Tags: loops, tensorflow, keras, memory, lstm

I am relatively new to Tensorflow and LSTM, have been working with it for a couple of months only. Currently, I am working on multivariate LSTM, and I want to use the same model configuration and loop over different data sets.

The problem that I encounter is that the memory is somehow retained, which means the next training results will be affected by previous training. Therefore, for example, if I train model 1 and 2 in a loop, and train model 2 separately, the results of model 2 in these two trials are different. Belows are my codes:

```
seed(1)
tf.random.set_seed(2)

#model configuration
epochs = 20
batch_size=100
no_models=24

for i in range(0,no_models):
    #Select X train and Y train from list
    #Select X test and Y test from list

    #model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(200, activation="sigmoid",#recurrent_activation="sigmoid",
    input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]),
    return_sequences=False,stateful=False,return_state=False))
    model.add(Dense(1,activation="sigmoid"))

    # compile model
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=rmse)

    for trn, val in kfold.split(X_train, Y_train):
        # fit model
        history = model.fit(X_train[trn], Y_train[trn], epochs=epochs,
        batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1)
    #make prediction
    model.fit(X_train,Y_train)
    Y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

I tried a few things to fix this:

- I already use random seed to have the same results for every run.
- I did tried creating the LSTM model as function, with all `model.add()`, `model.compile()`, `model.fit()`, `model.evaluate()` and `model.fit()` within that function, return Y_pred at the end.
- Clear session with `keras.clear_session()`
- Add `model = None` at the end of the loop
- Clear LSTM state with `model.reset_states()` at the end of the loop
- Put `del model` at the end of the loop

All to no avail. Somehow LSTM still retained the memory and affects the subsequent training.

I could do sth tedious like run all the models separately instead of doing a loop, but I have 24 models so that would be really annoying..

Does someone have encounter the same problem and have any ideas to fix this? All help is much appreciated. Also, this is my first time I posted here so I apologized if my post is not correctly following the rules, please kindly help me with the format of my post, not deleting it :(. Thanks!

Comment: You need to put the model inside your second for loop, so it is defined only for each fold.

Comment: I think that will take more computational time, since the model configuration is the same in both loops. I edited my code, after cross-validation I had trained the model again with all data, which I didn't realize that my initial post was missing that.

Comment: It does not matter, calling fit on a model does not do training for scratch, you need to create a new model for that.